# Calculated Fields and increments

Tags: filemaker

I am building a system using Starting Point and need help with calculated fields.

Basically when an estimate is created it takes the same ID as the project its linked to with a "-1" 1 being incremental value. So if the increment -1 exists the next estimate for that project would be -2 and so on.

So for example

**Project Id:** 120000

**First Estimate:** 120000-1

**Second Estimate:** 120000-2

I have found out how to add a hyphen and number after the project ID (the stored as estimate ID) like so `id_project & "-" & 1` but I have no idea using filemaker how to use calculated fields to look and see if 120000-2 is a thing and if it is make it 120000-3

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have at least a relationship between Projects and Estimates. Perhaps something like this (without the Estimates_self table occurrence, which I'll get to in a moment):

[image]

If you're in the Projects context (on a layout linked to the Projects table), you can get a count from there using something like `Count ( Estimates::id )`.

If you want to make this happen from the context of Estimates, create a self-join as shown above, using the project foreign key as the match field. Then you can use `Count ( Estimates_self::id )`.

Finally, an option without any relationship graph changes would be to use `ExecuteSQL`:

```
ExecuteSQL (
  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Estimates WHERE project_id = ?" ;
  "" ; "" ;
  Estimates::project_id
)
```

All of these will give you the number of estimates that a given project has. Add one to that and you have your suffix number for the new estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Count the related estimates based on a parent Project. This will give you the Estimate number after dash

Comment: How do I use count and functions like that in filemaker? I can only seem to be able to insert fields into calculated values rather than Db values. I am totally beginner with filemaker so forgive me if this is a stupid question,

Comment: When you insert fields into the calculation formula, FileMaker will evaluate the field value. The format is count( yourtable::yourfield ). You will need to create a self-relationship between estimates by their id_project.