# Filemaker calculated fields ExecuteSQL and Case

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to work with calculated fields in filemaker using FM starting point. I am very beginner with filmmaker and asked a question previous that I am now expanding on; [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472956/calculated-fields-and-increments). I am now moving estimates to invoices and similar to my previous question an estimate can have multiple invoices so I want to add a letter of the alphabet for each one. Based on the previous answer I'm trying to use the count function paired with 'case' (I was looking for an if statement and filemaker files seemed to suggest case is what I needed) to convert the count to letters. but it keeps asking me to use an operator but I'm not sure as to where I need this.

Here is my code, any help appreciated.

```
$var1 =
ExecuteSQL (
  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T12_INVOICES WHERE id_estimate = ?" ;
  "" ; "" ;
  T12_INVOICES::id_estimate
)
Case (
 $var1 = 1; "A";
 $var1 = 2; "B";
 $var1 = 3; "C";
 $var1 = 4; "D";
 $var1 = 5; "E";
 $var1 = 6; "F";
 $var1 = 7; "G";
 $var1 = 8; "H";
 $var1 = 9; "I";
 "Z"
)
id_estimate & $var1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
let([
$var1 = ExecuteSQL ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T12_INVOICES 
WHERE id_estimate = ?" ; "" ; "" ; T12_INVOICES::id_estimate);

$var2= Case (
$var1 = 1; "A";
$var1 = 2; "B";
$var1 = 3; "C";
$var1 = 4; "D";
$var1 = 5; "E";
$var1 = 6; "F";
$var1 = 7; "G";
$var1 = 8; "H";
$var1 = 9; "I";
"Z"
)];

id_estimate & $var2
)
```

Check out the Choose function for a simpler Case statement.

Comment: Thanks. I did look at the Let function but didn't think to have the two variables.

Comment: Quick question. Is it possible for this to be generated on creation? The programme that I use originally had the invoice ID generate a serial number set on creation. With the code above the ID works exactly how I want but as I guess it doesn't generate it on creation other things don't work with the process

Comment: Should work fine on creation, just remember to add 1 to the count as the current record isn't commited yet.

Comment: Hmm still struggling. What appears to be happening is there is a script that moves the estimate to invoices and at the bottom of that script there are some lines which move the lines in the estimate to a table separate from invoices and links via the invoice ID, this is the one that is not being inserted when using calculated values as opposed to serial generated on creation.

Comment: Sounds like you should insert a set field script step at the end of the script to do the estimate ID calculation instead of an autoenter in the field itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I figured it. I moved the Set Variable line to after the Set Fields and that seemed to solve it. Thanks for all your help.